# the first indexed image is rendered and it should be on screen for some time before componentDidMount loads up

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code where the first image and text renders up and even before it renders , the componentdDIDmount gets called and so we don't see the first image rendered on the screen .I want it to last on screen for say 10 seconds before setimeout runs in componentdidmount and second image is rendered .
Here is the link to the fiddle code which can seen online .I want 
this.backgrounds[0] to be on screen for some time before second screen loads .

````
  constructor(props){
      super(props)

      this.state={
          currrentIndex:0,
          count:0
      };
      this.backgroundImages=[img1,img2,img3];
      this.text=[
        'Personalising  an Insurance plan according to your needs',
        'Adding Points to your wallet',
        'Putting together Smart Financing Options',
        'Personalising  an Insurance plan according to your needs',

      ]

  }
  componentDidMount(){
      // hold it in this 

      this.timeOut=setTimeout(
          this.changeBackground,
          this.props.timer
      )
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {

    if (this.timeout) clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  }

  changeBackground= ()=> {
      // change the index and 
      console.log("this.state.currentIndex", this.state.currrentIndex);

    this.setState(function ({ currrentIndex }) {
      let nextBackgroundIndex;
       nextBackgroundIndex = ++this.state.currrentIndex
      return { currrentIndex: nextBackgroundIndex }
    }, function () {
      if(this.state.currrentIndex===4){
        this.props.changefirstuserstate()
      }
      else{
      this.timeout = setTimeout(
        this.changeBackground,
        this.props.timer || 5 * 1000
      )
    }})
  }
  //  else {
  //    debugger
  //   this.props.changefirstuserstate();
  //  }

//}


 render(){
   console.log("index is ", this.state.currrentIndex)
   if(this.state.currrentIndex===0){

    return(
      <ComponentWrapper>
        <ImageWrapper>
          {console.log('rendred index is ', this.state.currrentIndex)}
          <Image src={this.backgroundImages[0] }/>
          </ImageWrapper>

       <Text>Adding Points to your wallet</Text>
      </ComponentWrapper>
  )
   }
   else if (this.state.currrentIndex ===1){

    return(
      <ComponentWrapper>
        <ImageWrapper>
          {console.log('rendred index is ', this.state.currrentIndex)}
          <Image src={this.backgroundImages[1] }/>
          </ImageWrapper>

       <Text> Putting together Smart Financing Options</Text>
      </ComponentWrapper>
  )
   }
   else{

    return(
      <ComponentWrapper>
        <ImageWrapper>
          {console.log('rendred index is ', this.state.currrentIndex)}
          <Image src={this.backgroundImages[2] }/>
          </ImageWrapper>

       <Text>Personalising  an Insurance plan according to your needs</Text>
      </ComponentWrapper>
  )
   }

 }
}
export default SplashScreen```
````

Comment: So is the issue that the images take time to load and so the text appears before the images?

Comment: Yup .This is the same problem that i am facing now .

Comment: What you could do is render all of the images but give them a style of `display: none`. This way, the browser will download all of the images. Then instead of changing the entire image element, you can just remove the `display: none` from whichever image you want to have shown currently.